# serve zipped javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, gzip

I join all my external javascript files into one file. I make two version of this file. One is zipped, one is not. How to check the browser support gzip or not and serving a right file? And if browser support gzip, how to tell it this is a zipped file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not required to zip JavaScript file,
instead, you should use [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Apache will handle the compression and detect clients browser support gzip header.
If the clients browser support the gzip header, a compressed copy of JavaScript will be sent.

You can also explicitly set an expiration header for static files to better leverage on browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when your browser requests a page, it sends information on the content types/encodings it can accept, including (if applicable) whether it can accept gzipped content. So, you can check the header (I think it's the `Accept-encoding` header) to see if it has gzip in it.

Though, I'm pretty sure that the server handles this (checking for compression support and compressing files) itself if you set it up correctly.